# 9 digits in vertical arrangement

Tags: sliding-blocks

Here, 9 digits are given vertically on a board with 4 wings: North, West, South, East.

Your mission is to arrange them horizontally.

Pieces can move any distance in a move.

The first move is clearly to move the digit 7 to the west wing. We can denote it by 7W.

Note that 7W means “to move digit to the West wing” not “to move to the direction of west.”

[image]

Comment: How are you making these beautiful graphics?

Comment: @SlowMagic LaTeX + TikZ

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have found solution with only

> 25 moves (consecutive movements of 1 tile is 1 move)
>  42 moves (every move is counted separately)

Here an animation of the idea:

> [image: slider-gif]

And for completeness, all steps taken:

> 25 moves:
>  7W 6E 5E 4W 5W 6W 8W 3S 2E 1E 8N 6N 5N 4N 7N 1W 2W 3W 9E 7S 4W 5W 6W 8E 7N

> 42 moves:
>  7W 6S 6E 5S 5E 4S 4W 5W 6W 8N 8W 3S 2S 2E 1S 1E 8E 8N 6E 6N 5E 5N 4E 4N 7E 7N 1W 2W 3N 3W 9N 9E 7S 4S 4W 5S 5W 6S 6W 8S 8E 7N

Comment: If all consecutive movements of a single tile are considered 1 move, which apparently is the intention of the OP, then this is 26 moves, the same as ACB's solution.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, I know, but I already had this solution, before OP clarified how it should be counted. I was halfway of making this animation before he typed it in the chat, and it is still more efficient than the other answer. That's why I did post it anyway.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't meant as a complaint, just as added info. I really like your animation.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, ah ok, thanks :) I got a downvote at approx. the same time as your comment, so I assumed this was the explanation for that. Thanks for your clarification, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, If I count correctly, I come up with 25 moves :) I agreed with you initially, but we both counted wrong ;)

Comment: You're right, it's 25. I miscounted.

Comment: I am now wondering if we can get 24 moves? Or if the limit is 25? Any thoughts?

Comment: @newQOpenWid, I think so, but I am not 100% sure... do you have any progress with the code/algoritm? ;)

Comment: Wow. Good fellas. Y’all are smarter than me. :-)
My first solution is 28 moves. I expected one or two fewer solution. That’s the reason I posted this problem. But, I couldn’t imagine 25 moves solution is possible. 

Comment: @P.-S.Park, the only reason I tried to find a better solution, was because you said that there was a much better solution, you motivated me! The answer of ACB was very good already. So I am really glad there was indeed a better solution, haha! A really nice turn of events :D

Comment: I've just run a breadth first search on my computer, and if I did that right 25 moves is the shortest solution. Furthermore, there are no positions further than 25 moves away from the starting position so the the goal position is antipodal (though there are many other antipodes).

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Thank you for verifying!

Answer (score 32):

We can do it in

> **26 moves**, if we count consecutive movements of 1 tile as 1 move
>  <sup>(ex:- 8 North + 8 East = 8 to East wing = 1 move)</sup>
>  *or*
>  **43 moves**, if we count based on the directions in which a tile is going.
>  <sup>(ex:- 8 North + 8 East = 2 moves)</sup>

Using the suggested notation

> 26 moves
>
> ```
>  7W 8W 9W 6W 5W 4S 3S 2E 1E 5N 6N 9N 8N
>  7N 1W 2W 3W 4W 7S 8S 9E 8E 6S 5W 6W 7O
> ```
>
> 43 moves
>
> ```
>  7W 8N 8W 9N 9W 6S 6W 5S 5W 4S 3S
>  2S 2E 1S 1E 5E 5N 6E 6N 9E 9N 8E
>  8N 7E 7N 1W 2W 3N 3W 4N 4W 7S 8S
>  9S 9E 8N 8E 6S 5S 5W 6N 6W 7N
> ```

Or, if the notation is confusing you,

> [image: gif]

Comment: Great animation. Makes a potentially tricky process really simple to follow!

Comment: Good! But, it can be solved in less moves.

Comment: Yo the animation *slaps*

Comment: @P.-S.Park I am not seeing a better method right now. Let's see if any other can come up with that. I am also trying to find it.

Comment: @P.-S.Park, I have found a 42 solution. Or could it be even better? (Before I waste my time to create an animation for it ;))

Comment: @Lezzup I'm interested in the method of your solution, and I would love for you to create an anim/explanation.

Comment: @Lezzup You can reduce much more.

Comment: @P.-S.Park is it fine if I implement some code and use a search algorithm? or is that sacrilege? P.S. I found an alternate way to get to 43 which can use some improvement, is that a good partial answer?

Comment: Oh, sorry. My mistake. 
7W means “to move digit to the West wing” not “to move to the direction of west.”
So you’d recount your moves if you reduce 8N+8W to 8W.

Comment: @newQOpenWid It’s fine.

Comment: @P.-S.Park is it 26 then?

Comment: @newQOpenWid given the nature of the procedure, there should be several approaches with 43 moves. I found some later too.

Comment: @ABC, my first 6 or 7 tries all were with 43 moves, before I finally found one with 42. I'll post my answer this evening, when I have finished the animation

Comment: @P.-S.Park, is 25 moves the minimum? Or could it be reduced even more?